# Why does my breaker keep tripping after power failures?

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have a breaker that has only one outlet with two computers on it. It either trips when I plug the computers in or when the power comes back after a power out. It feels like it trips when the computer power supplies start charging their components after they have been discharged. It is a 16amp circuit on 240v and it is nowhere near its limit. Help!!

Comment: Where in the world are you Bob  16A 240V with computers sounds like UK ? Is your breaker a GFCI or AFCI ? How is the outlet a little loose, old ? How is the plug into the computer side - loose ??

Comment: I am in Eastern Europe. The outlet, breaker, cable and computers are all new

Comment: Look for a loose wire connection in the outlet and the breaker . (Unless they were replaced to solve this issue - I suspect a loose wire).

Comment: Is there a laser printer?  What is the power supply size of these PCs?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two PCs, it's possible that the inrush current could be 8A each.  That's a fairly common problem for switch-mode power supplies - their normal current draw is fairly low, but on power-on they can briefly draw a lot.  16A is lower than we'd use for a ring main in the UK.

You should also look for a genuine problem in the wiring though.  If you have any RCD plugs, try putting them on the mains cables to the PCs, in case there is a fault inside a PC.

Comment: 16A is a normal breaker size for those who use tree-wired mains and not ring mains.